# URL encoding issues between php page to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

I have a php page that receives url from ajax the url is going through `encodeURIComponent()` before its being post with ajax.

in the php page i tried both with `urldecode()` or without it. both ways return the same wrong url which contains `&amp;` instead of & i guess i could `str_replace` but i assume there is some other issue here and replace might not be the answer.

html/ajax code:

```
var ajax_url = $('#base_url').val() + 'xxx';
var url_to_search = encodeURIComponent($('#sometextfield').val());
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_url,
    data: { ajax_vari: "ajax", url_to_search: url_to_search}
    }).success(function(insertID) {
        alert(insertID);
    });
```

php page:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax_vari']) && $_POST['ajax_vari'] == 'ajax'){
     echo $_POST['url_to_search'];
     echo urlencode($_POST['url_to_search']);
}
```

example of the URLS:

**html/ajax**

Original URL:`http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/77754?feat=502857-GN2&page=men-s-mif-w-baseball-cap-black-bear&attrValue_0=Woodland&productId=1286129`

after `encodeURIComponent()`: `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.llbean.com%2Fllb%2Fshop%2F77754%3Ffeat%3D502857-GN2%26page%3Dmen-s-mif-w-baseball-cap-black-bear%26attrValue_0%3DWoodland%26productId%3D1286129`

**php page:**

after `urldecode()`:`http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/77754?feat=502857-GN2&amp;page=men-s-mif-w-baseball-cap-black-bear&amp;attrValue_0=Woodland&amp;productId=1286129`

without `urldecode()`:`http://www.llbean.com/llb/shop/77754?feat=502857-GN2&amp;page=men-s-mif-w-baseball-cap-black-bear&amp;attrValue_0=Woodland&amp;productId=1286129`

Thanks

Comment: Where are you getting the url from? Remember that PHP already decodes data going into $_GET/$_POST for you.

Comment: i enter the url manually into the html page that send the ajax call after encoding the url. and about php decoding the data - doesnt make much difference as in both examples with or without urldecode the answer returned are the same

Comment: what's the problem, then? `&amp;` is the proper way to put a `&` into a url. not everyone does it, but if you don't, the w3c validator will scream at you.

Comment: yea. but in some cases - like the one i gave above - the url with `&amp;` returns a different page then it would with &.

Comment: Post your actual code, please.

Comment: Added the ajax and php pages

Comment: Try to remove both `encodeURIComponent` in JS and  `urldecode` in PHP. It should work fine. jQuery (or browser itself? not sure) will encode passed data anyway.

Comment: Cannot remove encodeURIComponent - if i do addresses with space will fail.

Comment: Why they should fail? Not sure what are you doing later with those addresses in PHP, but you do not need to encode URLs in JS just in order to pass them to PHP correctly. If you will remove both encodeURI and urldecode like I said before, you should get an URL in PHP just as it was entered into `#sometextfield`. Later, if you need, you can encode it with PHP when you need that.